# JQuery Dialog - Replace Timeout with close button

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I am using the code below and decided I want a close button instead of the timeout.

How can I replace the timeout with a close button with the code below?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#info_box").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        modal: true,
            width: 400,
            zIndex: 9999999,
        resizable: false,
        open: function() {
            // close the dialog 10 secs after it's opened
            setTimeout(function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }, 10000);
        }
    });

    $(".notavailable").bind("click", function() {
        $("#info_box").dialog("open");
    });
});

</script>
```

Comment: Actually you can just remove the `open: function() {..}` part

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to add a `buttons` property to the `Object` the `dialog` is created with, something like:

```
$("#info_box").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: true,
    width: 400,
    zIndex: 9999999,
    resizable: false,
    buttons: [
        {
            text: "Close",
            click: function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
            }
        }
    ]
});
```